# consult select in laravel with eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm starting with Laravel and I have two simple entities that are users and notes, which are related as follows:

**User**

```
public function notes()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Note');
}
```

**Notes**

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Now within my controller notes with eloquent, I would like to return all the notes that I have, but instead of receiving the id of the user I would like to return the name of this, there something that I have to specify in the relationship of both entities or simply I should adjust something in my query, at the moment I am using this:

```
$notes = Note::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve user name as below:

```
$notes = Note:: orderBy ('id', 'desc') -> get ();
foreach ($notes as $note)
{
    $name = $note->user->name;
}
```

Comment: I need to return all records that exist of notes, why will I send them in json, can I do it this way?

Comment: @Criss What do you need? The name of all notes in a json?

Comment: As the question says I need to get all the records of my table notes, but instead of returning the user code in the record of each note, I need to return the name of this .. Then I need to send all this data in json .. of course there was thought of a foreach, but also hoped that there would be another simpler way with eloquent or is not it?

Comment: You can't do my way to return in json. To return all recodes of notes with user in json data, I think you should use join clause for notes and users table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the whole $note data with the 'user_name' define your own class first. Something like this.

```
class my_class{
    public $data;
    public $user_name;
}
```

You can run a loop just after you get the $note variable and save the data to a new array as this code here.

```
$notes = Note::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
//define an empty Array
$data_arry=array();

foreach($notes as $note)
{
    $custom=new my_class();
    $name=User::where('u_user_id', $note->n_user_id)->limit(1)->get(); 
    //First 'u_user_id' for column name in user table second 'n_user_id' for column name in note table 
    $user_name=$name[0]->u_user_name; // 'u_user_name' for column name of stored the name in user table

    //pushing data to the object
    $custom->data=$note;
    $custom->user_name=$user_name;

    $data_arry[]=$custom;
}
```

Now you can Manage data with new Array.